# Underpants on the outside

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

A news article today says

> The force’s rural crime team lambasted the owners of more than 200 cars who drove to the top of Snake Pass, a trans-Pennine road between Sheffield and Manchester on Saturday, and then expected the police to rescue them with their “magical snowmobiles”.
>
> “We’ll deal with what we can, but our underpants aren’t on the outside and we can only knock so much common sense back into society,”
>
> [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2021/jan/03/derbyshire-police-pan-stupid-hikers-for-defying-covid-rules-to-get-stuck-in-snow)

Is this merely a reference to fictional superheroes (such as Superman) as in

> [Elite readers](https://www.elitereaders.com/why-comics-superheroes-wear-underwear-outside/)

Or is there more to it?

Comment: Yes, it's a common 'superhero' trope. No deeper meaning

Comment: @JimMack It's a UK thing...

Comment: @Cascabel Its in New Zealand too.  Eg a local TV programme in the `80s had "He doesn't wear a shiny suit or fly across the screen. He doesn't wear his underpants outside his jeans he's Terry Teo, " in its tune song.   https://www.nzonscreen.com/title/terry-and-the-gunrunners-episode-one-1985

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a bit of a history behind this...

> The Guardian cartoonist Steve Bell used the allegation by Alastair Campbell that he had observed [(John) Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Major) tucking his shirt into his underpants to caricature him wearing his pants outside his trousers, as a ***pale grey echo of both Superman and Supermac***, a parody of Harold Macmillan

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Major)

["Super-Mac" was from a 1958 cartoon image of Harold Macmillan, and  became an enduring nickname for him. ]

An example of a Steve Bell political cartoon lampooning John Major...

[image]

The trope was taken up in the [Woody Allen movie *Bananas* (1971)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananas_(film)), in which an increasingly insane revolutionary leader overthrows a typical banana republic and begins to issue a number of strange executive actions. One of these is that underwear must be changed 7 times daily, and in order to facilitate checking compliance with this dictum the underwear must be worn on the outside.

Comment: Well, that's brilliant stuff. I suspected a rich vein but knew nothing of all that. Very wide perspective. I won't accept in a hurry but it seems a strong and informative front-runner.

Comment: @Anton 
During the 90s I worked at the British Language Centre...the director was staunch Labor from Manchester and we received The Guardian without fail...so this question literally leaped off the page at me.

Comment: I think I recognise the chap on the left, but who are the other two? // I'll never forget [the essence of] the quote from Nicholson-Joker: 'And now, folks, it's time for "Who do you trust!" Hubba, hubba, hubba! Money, money, money! Who do you trust? Me? I'm giving away free money. And where is the Batman?  _He's at home, washing his tights!_' [[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMcfU0vGI5w)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth they are Johnson, Osborne (gimp suit) and Cameron (condom).

Comment: Are you saying that the idea that superheros are characterized by the fact that they wear their underwear on the outside comes from Steve Bell? I find that very hard to believe and would expect that idea to be as old as the first appearance of Superman. It's a pretty common trope, in any case.

Comment: @terdon No, I am saying that the _explicit reference_ to wearing underpants on the outside was widely popularized by Steve Bell. I'm old enough to remember the The Adventures of Superman from the  1950s television, and I cannot recall anyone suggesting he was wearing his underwear on the outside. They were supposed to look like body-builder gym shorts. Insulting Superman was not very common, even amongst cynical New Yorkers. As  Jim Croce once said, "You don't tug on Superman's cape"

Comment: Dammit, now you've piqued my curiosity. I was born in 1980, and I cannot remember the first time I saw the underwear-on-the-outside trope, but I would be very surprised if it did indeed become popular through Bell's cartoons. I am not claiming it didn't, mind you, I just don't know and you've made me curious! Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Underpants on the outside surely pre-dates Steve Bell. Every former UK child would get the reference from slightly crap Halloween costumes (before supermarkets sold them) and 200 idiots getting stuck in  the snow certainly deserve lampooning.

Comment: Just so that we are clear...the OP did not ask for origin of the expression. They asked if there was more to it...there is. I answered that question.

Comment: I enjoyed all contributions! I am delighted at the obvious pleasure this have given us all, together with the cultural elucidations.

Answer (score 7):

On the possible origin of the trope:

From Piperson at [The Great Comic Book Heroes](http://thegreatcomicbookheroes.blogspot.com/2014/07/men-in-tights-history.html)

> **Men in Tights - a history**
>
> When Superman first hit the scene with his blue and red tights it
> created a shockwave around the country that it hit off the whole
> superhero craze that is going on stronger than ever today with
> blockbuster movies like Batman and the Avengers. Before that no one
> had ever seen a hero in tights and cape. Where did they get the idea
> from?

[image]

> Siegel and Shuster created a character called Superman in 1933 though
> it bore very little resemblance to the Superman we know. He had mental
> powers but had normal strength. A year later they would re-envision
> him into a super crime fighter.
>
> *From Wikipedia on the creation of Superman - “The pair re-envisioned*
> *the character, who became more of a hero in the mythic tradition,*
> *inspired by such characters as Samson and Hercules, who would right*
> *the wrongs of Siegel and Shuster's times, fighting for social justice*
> *and against tyranny. It was at this stage the costume was introduced,*
> *Siegel later recalling that they created a "kind of costume and let's*
> *give him a big S on his chest, and a cape, make him as colorful as we*
> *can and as distinctive as we can."*
>
> *"The design was based in part on the costumes worn by characters in*
> *outer space settings published in pulp magazines, as well as comic*
> *strips such as Flash Gordon, [Doctor Occult, the Phantom,] and also*
> *partly suggested by the traditional circus strong-man outfit, which*
> *comprised a pair of shorts worn over a contrasting bodysuit."*
>
> Around this same time Alex Raymond's Flash Gordon hit the funny
> papers. He would often wear tights and cape so it's not very far
> fetched to imagine that this very popular strip was a big inspiration
> for the creation of Superman.

Comment: So to summarize for the OP, "our underpants aren’t on the outside" is not a set phrase or idiom but is a jocular understandable reference implying that "we're not superheroes", because superheroes wear underwear on the outside.

Comment: Thank you Mitch.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Between your answer and mine, I think we have a fine response to this complicated topic...+1

Comment: My thanks to all who contributed. I am enlightened, entertained and made very cheerful by all you have written. I may only accept one answer, could have chosen either, but have gone for the politically broader one. I am grateful to you all.

Comment: I'll come back tomorrow and downvote myself for lowering the tone of the site. Not even Batman.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh please do not! It was all glorious lighthearted English that warms our grim winter days. "Now is the winter of our disconbobulation,"

Comment: @Anton - I must object to your misquoting the great Bard.  "Discombobulation" is spelled with an "m" before the "b" not an "n".

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Oops - I will wash my mouth out with champagne. Your name eventually stimulated me to read about monica: a sad and murky tale from before my main time here.